# How can I prove an integral equation?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I got stuck with this problem, while studying distributions and applications to differential equations, and cannot get out of it: if $r:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the function $r(t)=e^{-3 \left|t\right|}$, how can I check that exists $u \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ solution of the equation $u(t)=r(t)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(x)r(t-x)dx$?
Any help or suggestion to approach the proof is very welcome..

Comment: Apply Fourier transform on both sides. Note that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(x)r(t-x)dx$ is the convolution of $u$ and $r$ and that the Fourier transform of a convolution is the product of the Fourier transforms of each of the factors.

Comment: Thank you! But once I do it: $\hat{u}=\hat{r}+\hat{u}\hat{r}$ I still did not prove the existence of a solution $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$… or probably am I missing something?

Comment: From the resulting equation you get that $\hat{u}=\frac{\hat{r}}{1-\hat{r}}$. You have to show that $\frac{\hat{r}}{1-\hat{r}}$ has an inverse Fourier transform in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thank you, and since $\hat{r}(t)=\int e^{ikt}e^{-3\left|t\right|} dt$, i should solve $u(t)=\int\frac{dt}{2 \pi} \left( \frac{\hat{u}}{1-\hat{u}}\right)e^{-ikt}$, am I understanding right?

Comment: To prove that it exists you don't necessarily need to have an explicit formula. I haven't computed anything, but if the question is existence I would just check that the integral for the inverse transform converges and gives an $L^2$ function.

Comment: Understood, thank you a lot!